# dotted glossary, listed alphabetically

Tags: glossaries

i am a absolute newbe to latex and after struggeling almost the whole day with a (i guess simple) glossary, i came up to post my question...

i tried to ma a glossary (intended to serve as my master thesis' "list of abbrievations"). it should be ordered alphabetically and between the abbrieviation and its meaning i'd love to see a dotted line.

i came up to [Glossary/Abbreviations list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/352516/glossary-abbreviations-list?newreg=83ed1b0d538947b3aee789e69b4dd5c8) and tried to translate this to my report - it just doesn't work. even if i create a new document and just copy-paste the instructions, i just get a blank but numbered pdf with really NOTHING in it...

can anybody help me please?
i ran the mikTex update - nothings helps...

thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Have a look at the `glossaries` package documentation. If you want to use that package, you need to process your document first with `latex`, then with the `makeglossaries` script that comes with that package, and then again with `latex`.

Answer (score 1):

The main attraction of the `glossaries` package is that it produces not only a term-definition list, but also can list, for each term, the pages in the document body that actually mention that term. If you don't need that, a simple table like the one below may be sufficient.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lmodern,array,ragged2e,booktabs,calc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.35}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}

\makeatletter % vertically aligned dotted leaders according to
              % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109759
              % the optional argument sets the spacing between dots
\newcommand \Dotfill[1][0.35em]{\hspace{#1}\leavevmode \leaders \hb@xt@ #1{\hss .\hss }\hfill \kern \z@}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{}>{\RaggedRight}p{1.25in}<{\Dotfill}>{\RaggedRight}p{3.5in}@{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{Term} & Definition \tabularnewline
\midrule
Ducks & Aquatic bird often misused to showcase TikZ drawing capabilities \tabularnewline
Parrot & Tropical bird from Norway, known to be pining for the Fjords when appearing dead \tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks first of all!
is there a way, how to order that tabular alphebetically (left collumn)? Furthermore, could i skip the horizontal lines and the "Term", "Definition" part?
thanks you!!

Comment: i managed the optical adaption, but is there any option to order the list alphabetically?

Comment: The `glossaries` package does that for you, but a simple table does not. I don't find manual sorting particularly onerous, but that is your call.