# Dotfill like in the Table of Contents

Tags: tables, table-of-contents

I would like to make a custom table with symmetrical dot leader like in the table of contents or on the picture

[image: What i want]

But when I use `\dotfill`:

```latex
\documentclass[pdftex,12pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lll}
Item   & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Цена, р.} \\
\hline
& 2018 г. & 2019 г.\\
Е д а:\\
Мясо\dotfill     & 2500 (10 кг. по 250/кг.) & 2790 (10 кг. свинины)\\
Сосиски\dotfill  & 2500 (5 кг.)             & 450 (4,5 кг.)\\
Огурцы\dotfill   & 500                      & 80 (3 кг.)\\
Помидоры\dotfill & 500                      & 60 (2 кг.)\\
Зелень\dotfill   && 220\\
Лук\dotfill      & 60 (4-5 шт.)             & 50\\
Специи\dotfill   & 500                      & 1050\\
Кетчуп\dotfill   & 240 (3 по 0,5 л.)        & 120 (3 упаковки)\\
Уксус\dotfill    & 80\\
Хлеб\dotfill     &                          & 320 (7 буханок)\\
\hline
Всего            &6880                      & 5140\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

I get the following:

[image: What I get]

How can I get the desirable symmetrical dotfill in a custom table?

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) as always on this site, you are much more likely to get help if you provide a full but minimal example that others can copy and test as is. Here there is no document class or relevant preamble.

Comment: You could use a fixed width colum type for the first column

Comment: Thank you for your advice, daleif. I have added the preamble.

Comment: Leandriis, thank you. I've tried fixed column type, but it doesn't make \dotfill symmetrical.

Comment: You are already using `tabularx` have you tried `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Xll}` instead (remember to change the end part as well)

Comment: No, `tabularx` didn't help.

Comment: What exactly does "symmetrical"  mean in this context?

Comment: Well in my version the `tabularx` example will give the first column a lot more room, and this the `\dotfill`  are more prominent.

Comment: What I mean by "symmetrical" is how dots are aligned in the first picture or in the default table of contents: in the first column text is aligned by the left side of the column, while dots are aligned by the right side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Edit

Now I see: You need [`\leaders`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/109778/220875), like here:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
% \usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs,microtype}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand \dotfill {\leavevmode \leaders \hb@xt@ .44em{\hss .\hss }\hfill \kern \z@}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{p{3cm}ll}
Item   & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Цена, р.} \\
\toprule
& 2018 г. & 2019 г.\\
Е д а:\\
Мясо\dotfill     & 2500 (10 кг. по 250/кг.) & 2790 (10 кг. свинины)\\
Сосиски\dotfill  & 2500 (5 кг.)             & 450 (4,5 кг.)\\
Огурцы\dotfill   & 500                      & 80 (3 кг.)\\
Помидоры\dotfill & 500                      & 60 (2 кг.)\\
Зелень\dotfill   && 220\\
Лук\dotfill      & 60 (4-5 шт.)             & 50\\
Специи\dotfill   & 500                      & 1050\\
Кетчуп\dotfill   & 240 (3 по 0,5 л.)        & 120 (3 упаковки)\\
Уксус\dotfill    & 80\\
Хлеб\dotfill     &                          & 320 (7 буханок)\\
\midrule
Всего            &6880                      & 5140\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: table with leader and dotfill]